# Python sqlalchemy : table with no primary keys and duplicate values?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using an existing database made by a third party with sqlalchemy. However, I'm having trouble as the tables do not have primar keys, and what's worse, they have duplicate elements for each row, so I can't pick an existing column as primary key. The tables have two columns: both have non-unique values.

I tried to monkey-patch the table as per http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/10/sqlalchemy-connecting-to-pre-existing-databases/ but apparently this does not work (see below)

My current code is (`MirnaTable` is my mapped class, basically just a skeleton with nothing else)

```
connection = create_engine("sqlite:///targets.sqlite")
metadata = MetaData(bind=connection)
db_table = Table("miranda", metadata,
                 Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                 autoload=True)
mapper(MirnaTable, db_table)
Session = sessionmaker(connection)
session = Session()
```

Then I try for example issuing

```
all_records = session.query(MirnaTable).all()
```

And I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such column: miranda.id 
u'SELECT miranda.gene_id AS miranda_gene_id, miranda."mature_miRNA" AS
"miranda_mature_miRNA", miranda.id AS miranda_id \nFROM miranda' ()
```

So of course the id column isn't found. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As requested, here is an example from the table (retrieved directly from sqlite):

```
gene  mature_miRNA 
---- -------------
80205  hsa-miR-200c 
80205  hsa-miR-200c 
9693  hsa-miR-200c 
9693  hsa-miR-200c 
9881  hsa-miR-200c 
9710  hsa-miR-200c 
9750  hsa-miR-200c
```

Comment: Could you post the table with example data please?

Comment: Done: there's a sample of what kind of data you can expect now.

Comment: ORM won't work without something that can serve as an identity of row.  Consider using the table directly without mapping it to class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the post you refer to. You have to choose an *existing* column and define it as primary. It's also possible to setup composite primary key by putting them all in definition. In your case I think a gene has several mature microRNA, so the primary key should probably consist of `(gene_id, mature_miRNA)` pair. Since there is no more fields in the table, there is no need in `autoload=True` flag.

```
db_table = Table("miranda", metadata,
                 Column("gene_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                 Column("mature_miRNA", Integer, primary_key=True))
```

I don't know the types of fields in your table, so change them appropriately if they are not integer.

Comment: It works, great. I set the types accordingly and now I get correct results (compared with a standard query using sqlite3).

Comment: According to your updated data in the question these pairs are not unique too, so they can't serve as primary key. Some parts of ORM like simple queries work, some others can be cheated with disabled reload. But don't expect that everything will work.

Comment: I mostly use equality and IN (it's a really simple use case), but I'm going to do some accurate tests just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Change Column **id** to **rowid** for sqlite database

*original*:

```
db_table = Table("miranda", metadata,
                 Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                 autoload=True)
```

*modified*:

```
db_table = Table("miranda", metadata,
                 Column("rowid", Integer, primary_key=True),
                 autoload=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the id column exists first off and then that you have tried both upper and lower case.

It is also possible to set two primary keys for the table:

```
Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
Column("secondColumn", Integer, primary_key=True)
```

However this may cause update anomalies if any other row matches this row exactly. You might be best recreating the table and inserting your own PK column

Comment: I can do that but I'd try to avoid this, as it comes from a third-party and it would mean forking such a database with all the problems that esue. Also, both columns (exept the one I try to monkey-patch in) have duplicated values (yes, a mess, but I didn't do that...). EDIT: Forgot to say, the "id" column doesn't exist. I followed the example linked in the question to monkey-patch the table (but it didn't work).